# How to randomize the carousel function below?

Tags: html, dom

Below is the code that i have to rotate images on my site. However, i am having trouble trying to get it to randomize the starting image.

```
<script>
// Automatic Slideshow - change image every 4 seconds
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `Math.random()` to get an index between `0` and length of `.mySlides`, and initialize `myIndex` with that index, instead of `0`.

Comment: Also here -> `if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}` you should set `myIndex = 0` to go back to the first image.